# South Korea tourist visa from Japan

Tags: visas

If we apply for a.tourist visa at the embassy of South Korea in Tokyo, and we get rejected, will they put the rejected seal on the passport (Indian pasport holder)?

Comment: There's no "seal" on the passport, but rejected visa applications will be logged in the immigration computers.

Answer (score 1):

Like many countries, the Republic of Korea would not put a visa refusal/rejected stamp in your passport. It would, however, record it as data in its electronic immigration system.